# Can we change file without readin it into a memory, if we know that size of file will not change? c++

Tags: c++, fstream

I know that we can use `.seekg()` for `std::ifstream` and read from different places in file with out reading it all in memory. How can we write in different places in file, if we know that size of the file will not change after our actions (*we want just change some bytes*) **without copy it into a memory** and saving it as new file?

For example: I have file:

```
abcdefgh1234567890
```

I want to set 'de' into a '00':

```
abc00fgh1234567890
```

But my file is too large for reading it all into my memory

Comment: FYI: [std::ostream::seekp()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/seekp)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat OMG it's it

Comment: Out of curiosity: How large is your file exactly? ;-) My box has 32 GB main memory (where, of course, parts are occupied by OS and other applications). However, closing every application which is not needed permanently, there should be at least 20 GB available which could be used. Do you really intend to modify a file which that large? (I even don't know where to find such a big file on my disc.)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat I do my home work for university, and I try to create virtual HDD/SSD and I don't know how large it can be, user can create and 64 gb HDD, for example.
But just for example: On my pc I have one movie in 4k and it's 67 gb, and there is part of simbad star database - 16 gb, we can find very big files)

Comment: I see - video files. Sorry, I'm old-fashioned and still use the TV to watch movies... ;-)

Comment: If you need to read the bytes to choose the new bytes, or need to read file headers to find them, you use `fstream` that can do input and output.  (This is the use case that motivates that feature.)